VSCode integration with GitLab
I use GitLab and recently started working with VSCode. To integrate them I installed the GitLab workflow extention, added my gitlab acount. as per the instructions I created a new public project in gitlab. then I created a vuejs project in my vscode. I also connected my vue project to my repo using the gitlab workflow. then I typed the following commands in my terminal :
git add .
git commit -m "initial commit"
git push -u origin master
However I received the following message:

remote: HTTP Basic: Access denied. If a password was provided for Git
authentication, the password was incorrect or you're required to use a
token instead of a password. If a token was provided, it was either
incorrect, expired, or improperly scoped. See
https://gitlab.com/help/topics/git/troubleshooting_git.md#error-on-git-fetch-http-basic-access-denied
fatal: Authentication failed for
'https://gitlab.com/kalina199/second-test-project.git/'

I disconnected and connected my gitlab account, used OAuth, tokens with different rights, reinstalled the extension, created several projects and still got the same error message
I even tried without gitlab workflow, somehow MS Code opened link to authorize read/write  rights but when I tried to push I received the following:
! [remote rejected] main -> main (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://gitlab.com/kalina199/third-test-project.git'
